# Error : getting an object from an NSMutableArray - objective C

Tags: objective-c, class

I have the following code:

```
Product product = [[Product alloc] init];
product.title = tag; 
[allProducts addObject:product];
NSString *pImage = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:p.title];
```

But it is failing to return anything

Can anyone kindly help me please?
THanks

Comment: should be Product* product = [[Product alloc] init];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing in your code is trying to retrieve anything from a collection.

```
[allProducts addObject:product];
```

The line above is used for adding objects. If you are looking to retrieve an object you do:

```
Product* product = [allProducts objectAtIndex:0];
```

Look at the documentation for [NSArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSArray) and NSMutableArray.

--update--

Just noticed you have an error in your code:

```
Product* product = [[Product alloc] init];
```

(you left out the *)

Comment: and you just added an extra `]` :)

Comment: @Toastor - OOOOOOOOOOOOOOPS :)